# Black Screen on ubuntu with error

Tags: system-installation

I was using LiveUsb to use Ubuntu after my ubuntu got kernel panic. Now when I was trying use ubuntu without installation black screen appeared. When I pressed esc I am able to read 4 messages :-

> ```
> SQUASHFS error : zlib decompression failed, data probably corrupt
> SQUASHFS error : squashfs_read_data failed to read block 0x27b27c6f
> SQUASHFS error : Unable to read fragment cache entry [27b27c6f]
> SQUASHFS error : Unable to read page, block 27b27c6f, size 70b4.
> ```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did the live USB successfully boot to a desktop (in "Try before install" mode)? And have you tested the memory (`memtest` on the live usb should work) to see if bad RAM caused this error, and your previous problems?

Answer (score 0):

Running a live, you might first run an fsck on the partitions containing the  .squash files.
Next, once all the errors will be fixed, you can proceed by overwriting the current .squash with the original copy, if you have it.

Comment: What are you trying to say ?

Comment: Perhaps the usb live is corrupted

Comment: No way. Tried it in two usb's

Comment: Did you try to change the usb port?  Did you try to use another ISO for the usb live?

Comment: Yes I changed the usb port but not the iso. Well I'll try that.

Comment: @HimagraChawla If you didn't verify (md5sum...) the ISO before creating the USB, it could create corrupted live USB's all day long. And your program/method of creating a live USB may be flawed and always create corrupted live USB's. The error clearly says "data probably corrupt" so either the file is bad, or the usb is bad, or your RAM is bad (or several)

Comment: md5sum was correct. Verified.

Comment: Can you try the USB on another pc? Can you get the command prompt??